# Avoiding null pointer crashes in C++ by overloading operators - bad practice?

Tags: c++, qt, operator-overloading, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm starting to write a rather large Qt application and instead of using raw pointers I want to use smart pointers, as well as Qt's own guarded pointer called QPointer.

With both standard library smart pointers and Qt's pointers the application crashes when a NULL pointer is dereferenced.

My idea was that I could add a custom overload to the dereference operators * and -> of these pointer types that check if the pointer is NULL.

Below is a short example that works fine so far. If a NULL pointer was dereferenced, a temporary dummy object would be created so that the application does not crash. How this dummy object would be processed might not be always correct, but at least there would be no crash and I could even react on this and show a warning or write it to a log file.

```
template <class T>
class Ptr : public std::shared_ptr<T> {

private:
  T * m_temp;

public:
  Ptr<T>(T * ptr) : std::shared_ptr<T>(ptr), m_temp(NULL) {}
  ~Ptr() { 
    if (m_temp) {
      delete m_temp;
    }
  }
  T * operator->() {
    if (!std::shared_ptr<T>::get()) {
      if (m_temp) {
        delete m_temp;
      }
      m_temp = new T();
      return m_temp;
    } else {
      return std::shared_ptr<T>::get();
    }
  }
  T & operator*() {
    return *operator->();
  }
};
```

Of course I'll be doing NULL checks and try to eliminate the source of NULL pointers as much as possible, but for the rare case that it I forget a NULL check and the exception occurs, could this be a good way of handling it? Or is this a bad idea?

Comment: My hunch is that this will require you to expend a bunch of effort in service of making errors in your code harder to detect. That doesn't seem worthwhile to me.

Comment: Application crashes are a gift from <insert deity of choice here>. They let you know without any ambiguity that there is a bug in the code. Why would you hide this information from yourself? Do you struggle with that much self-loathing?

Comment: You end up in more of a mess as the original bug is hidden only to cause later problems.  In summary _"crash early, crash often"_ and fix them.

Comment: But say you do want to carry through. Constructing an object probably isn't enough. You needs to construct a **correctly configured** object to keep from simply moving the visible manifestation of the bug somewhere new. And if the object is null, as in it's not there, how can you possibly correctly configure it other than by dumb luck?

Comment: Mixing `shared_ptr` (and `unique_ptr`) with `QObject` and especially with `QWidget` is often an extremely bad idea. The reason is that objects and widgets are often organized in owning parent-child structures and if a parent deletes its children while they are still pointed to with some std smart pointer will inevitable lead to a bug, most often crash. You cannot also use `deleteLater()` when you are holding a `QObject` with smart std pointer. On the other hand it is often good practice to use non-owning `QPointer`s to `QObjects` and `QWidgets`. I would advice you not trying to reinvent wheel.

Comment: To sum up: prefer using parent-child relationships for `QObjects`. Note that parent-child relations are used AUTOMATICALLY for `QWidget`s and you cannot change it! For non-owning weak pointers use `QPointer`. If you decide to use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` to `QObject`, make sure they do not have a parent. And never user them for `QWidget`s.

Comment: I may not have been clear enough about Qt's pointers enough, sure I'd use Qt's (guarded) pointer types for Qt widgets and objects. The same logic from my above example could be implemented to a Qt pointer type.

Comment: QPointers get NULLed when they have been deleted. So if they were to be accidentally dereferenced when they are NULL, an empty widget would be created and there would be no crash.

Comment: That may be true, but would you get the correct behaviour? I would say not because by accessing a null pointer in the first place the program's got a bug in some earlier book-keeping that made the access possible. The best case I can see for you is this does nothing but hide an existing problem. The more likely result is it will create new problems. Don't do this. Find out why the program is accessing nulls and fix that.

Comment: _My idea was that I could add a custom overload to the dereference operators * and -> of these pointer types that check if the pointer is NULL._  And then what? Check it up front, if a null pointer is a legitimate possibility, otherwise, if and when your program crashes, debug it.

Comment: The trade-off of such a scheme is that it makes it harder to detect some errors that should be corrected.  That can give users of your class a false sense of confidence about absence of errors in their code when (as with `QObject`, etc) there are parent/child relationships between objects - so tends to set the scene for more complicated situations with errors that are even harder to track down.     It also doesn't address problems due to accessing the value (let alone dereferencing) uninitialised pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a bad idea for a few reasons:

1. You cannot derive from standard library types. It may work until you change something benign in your code and then it breaks. There are various things you can do to make this more acceptable, but the easiest thing is to just not do this.
2. There are more ways to create a shared_ptr than just a constructor call. Duplicating the pointer value in your `m_temp` variable is likely just to lead things to be out of sync and cause more problems. By the time you cover all the bases, you will have probably re-implemented the whole shared_ptr class.
3. `m_temp = new T();` seems like a frankly crazy thing to do if the old pointer is null. What about all the state stored in the object that was previously null? What about constructor parameters? Any initialization for the pointer? Sure, you could maybe handle all of these, but by that point you might as well handle the nullptr check elsewhere where things will be clearer.
4. You don't want to hide values being nullptr. If you have code using a pointer, it should care about the value of that pointer. If it is null and that is unexpected, then something further up the chain likely went wrong and you should be handling that appropriately (exceptions, error codes, logging, etc.). Silently allocating a new pointer will just hide the original source of the error. Whenever there is something wrong in a program, you want to stop or address the problem as close to the source as possible - it makes debugging the problem simpler.

A side note, if you are confident that your pointers are not null and don't want to have to deal with nullptr in a block of code, you may be able to use references instead. For example:

```
void fun1(MyObject* obj) {}
void fun2(MyObject& obj) {}
```

In `fun1`, the code might need to check for nullptr to be well written. In `fun2`, there is no need to check for nullptr because if someone converts a nullptr to a reference they have already broken the rules. `fun2` pushes any responsibility for checking the pointer value higher up the stack. This can be good in some cases (just don't try and store the reference for later). Note that you can use `operator *` on a `shared_ptr`/`unique_ptr` to get a reference directly.